# How to solve permission denied error for phantom js in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I am working on a laravel project where I am trying to use [php wrapper of phantom](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) js made by jonnyw. I have done everything written in the [docs](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/2-installation/).

I have downloaded the 32 bit executable file and set the path in my code, but it still gives me the following error:
**sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/: Permission denied**

My code looks like this

```
$client = PhantomJs::getInstance();
$client->getEngine()->setPath('/usr/local/bin/');
```

I have read some related [issues](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/16) already.

I am using laravel 5.4 and 4.0 version of jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring the internet and hours of deep digging I have been able to identify the solution.

Actually the solution is two fold:

1. We have to specify the relative path of phantomjs executeable file, **not the folder containing it**.
2. The phantom js executable file should be inside the laravel project, particularly in this case.

So in my case the correct path is

```
$client->getEngine()->setPath(base_path('vendor/bin/phantomjs'));
```

Where **phantomjs** is the executable file itself not the folder/directory containing it.

I hope it will be helpful for people like me.